# How to get 2 background colors depending on the percentage, i select

Tags: html, css

This is my code, but it have one problem. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntb1kcns/)

```html
<div style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, #cc2900 51%, #b3b3b3 49%);">
<h1>
Hi all, this is my div 1 
</h1>
</div>
<br><br>

<div style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, #cc2900 10%, #b3b3b3 90%);">
<h1>
Hi all, this is my div 2 
</h1>
</div>
```

The problem is:

If the red color is less than 50%, then the color changes to gradient..how to stop that?

Comment: The percentage specifies the start and stop location of the gradient. Try specifying 10% and 9% for example (10% - 90% means, start with red, from 10% until 90% fade red to grey, after that keep the grey color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the second colour stop at the wrong position, given your first example, it should be a value less than the first stop.

```html
<div style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, #cc2900 51%, #b3b3b3 49%);">
<h1>
Hi all, this is my div 1 
</h1>
</div>
<br><br>

<div style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, #cc2900 10%, #b3b3b3 9%);">
<h1>
Hi all, this is my div 2 
</h1>
</div>
```